# What is the best practice to deserialize a JSON object with field that might be either string or int?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to use Newton Json Deserializer to deserialize json object which looks like this:

```
{
  "grades": 97
}

Or this:

{
  "grades": ""
}
```

I wonder how should I properly define a [DTO](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) class in C# to represent the this object? Thanks!

Comment: why don´t you define grades as Object on your class?

Comment: But that relies on the fact that the deserializer can internally successfully deserialize the grades to the proper type (int or string) and assign it to the object field, right? I wonder if that happens?

Comment: An int cannot hold a string, but a string can hold an int.

Comment: Are you asking for arbitrary string or just empty string `""`?

Comment: @IvanStoev For my case empty string, but I would like to hear elegant solutions for the more general case.

Comment: Well, there is no elegant solution for general case than using `object` or `dynamic`. But for your specific case, you could simply use `int?`

Comment: @LifuHuang But "" is not only empty `string` . Any nullable type in C# will became `null` if grades are "". But if grades are something like "3ds" then you have to use some dynamic approach.

Comment: A custom JsonConverter is pretty simple to make for these type of things. I have provided an answer that might be useful.

Comment: Are you in control of the API or are you dealing with a third party API. This is an awful design. If you are in control, use null or undefined in place of "" and rely nullable types such as `int?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try with `dynamic` keyword:

```
public class Rootobject
{
     public dynamic grades { get; set; }
}
```

It will work with both `string` and `int`. For more info refer to [using dynamic type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx).

**UPDATE:**

Then to convert into `int` or `string` I will use `Convert.ToString()` because it handles `null` values and for `int` I will use `Int32.TryParse()` because I can better control conversion to `int` if input `drades` are not properly formatted.

**UPDATE:**

Any nullable type in C# will become `null` if grades are "". For that purpose, you can use `int?`. But if grades are something like "3ds" then you have to use some dynamic approach.

Comment: Than how should I convert it to proper type? by try-catch a runtime conversion exception or any more elegant ways? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, accidentally edited your answer, just ignore that.

Comment: It doesn't matter but let's say string.

Comment: For `string` I will use  `Convert.ToString()` because it handles `null` values and for `int` I will use `Int32.TryParse()` because you can better controll conversion to `int`.

Comment: The 2nd update really is the correct answer. You should have a code example of that in your answer instead of the dynamic.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for your inputs. By "dynamic" I was thinking to use `dynamic` or `object` types. But definitely you encouraged me to update answer with some more sophisticated and I will do that.

Comment: A custom JsonConverter would be more appropriate in my opinion. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use a custom JsonConverter on your POCO, which would ensure that the object gets deserialized into one expected type, rather than using `object` or `dynamic`, and then having to treat that property with suspicion throughout your codebase.

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class IntConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value.GetType() == typeof(int))
            writer.WriteValue((int)value);
        else
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        ParseInt(reader.Value.ToString());

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        objectType == typeof(int) || objectType == typeof(string);

    private static int ParseInt(string value)
    {
        int parsedInt = 0;
        int.TryParse(value, out parsedInt);
        return parsedInt;
    }
}
```

And then use this JsonConverter in your POCO like this:

```
public class Student
{
    [JsonProperty("grades"), 
    JsonConverter(typeof(IntConverter))]
    public int Grades;
}
```

I would find this is 'best practice' for these things.

Comment: I think that to match the question it should use `int?`

Comment: Why would you want to make it nullable, @CyprienAutexier

Comment: from what I understand from his use case, "" means `no grade` which is different from 0. in your DTO and your converter "" is considered as a 0.

Comment: @CyprienAutexier Let's agree to disagree on that one. Nulls are evil in my opinion.

Comment: Well, my point is not to discuss if they are evil or not, but just that you are considering `0 === ""` which is not the case, and makes you response a partial answer to the model shown by the OP.

Comment: According to the question he wants to **deserialize** transmitted data. If he wants to change the behavior of the serialization, that's fine. But the question did not tell how he was intending to use this information in his application, and thus - this is what one can do with the given information. Apparently he liked my answer enough to accept it as well.

Comment: Deserialize should keep the information, and you are loosing information here. Btw, your answer is not accepted, and the only upvote so far is mine ;), But we are one the edge of trolling now, so I'm done

Comment: With the risk of sounding like someone that needs the last word, I'll end with saying - that deserializing depends on your needs. If the source input is a mess from the beginning, it's about interpreting that to the best of your abilities, and perhaps now keeping the mess in your application if you don't need to. Anyways, thanks for the discussion.